# PTIJ: 50% of laser light on the floor of a Sukkah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

From the Gemara of Sukkah, it was argued that if the light at the bottom of the Sukkah is 50% light, 50% dark, then the Schach must be Kosher, since light expands as it travels from the top to the bottom (meaning that there must be more shade than sun on the top). But what would be the Halacha if the solar light came in the form of a laser beam? Lasers travels in a straight line, which would mean that 50% of light on the floor of the Sukkah would imply 50% of Schach on the top, possibly making it Passul. What should one do if their solar system implemented laser light?

[image: Regular light vs laser light]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: completely seriously, though, the sun is so far away that by the time the rays of light reach us, they are effectively perfectly straight. The diffusion effect is for completely different reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to give the laser a drink of wine . Then nothing will look so straight anymore.